# How do I load something when the page is selected?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to make a form with a lot of pages. So far it works ok and I added the controls from the code. There are hundreds of them and it makes the app "heavy".
Now I'm adding all the stuff in the comboboxes in at Initialization but what I want to do is to load the Controls when I change the page.
So when I start the form the controls should be loaded for page 1. What I want to do is when I click on Page 2 of the Multipage to load it's components (instead of adding all of them at the initialization of the UserForm).
Thanks!

Comment: I think you are running fast into the limitations of Excel/VBA here.

Comment: Yes ja72, I think I do... Unfortunately they don't allow me with executables at my company and Excel is my only tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to initialize each page only when it becomes clicked, you can track which has been clicked using something like;

```
Private mbInitialised() As Boolean

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ReDim mbInitialised(MultiPage1.Pages.Count - 1)
    SetupPage 0
End Sub

Private Sub MultiPage1_Change()
    SetupPage MultiPage1.Value
End Sub

Private Sub SetupPage(index As Integer)
    If (mbInitialised(index)) Then Exit Sub
    mbInitialised(index) = True
    MsgBox "init page " & index + 1
    '//setup here
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an easier way to do it

> Load UserForm: UserForm.MultiPage1.Value = 0: UserForm.Show

where the multipage value starts to **"page1"** as arrays starts from zero

if you want a different page change .Value = 0 into the page value - 1

ex:

> Load UserForm: UserForm.MultiPage1**.Value = 4** : UserForm.Show

this will take you to **"page3"** of multipage upon initializing userform

*edit:
 misunderstood the question a bit, my code will take you to the page but not execute something when changing pages, use Alex's code instead